# Magento 1.8.1 - Remove other shipping methods if free shipping is active on Estimate Shipping Block

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, estimate

I have an eshop developed using Magento 1.8.1.

I managed to remove other shipping methods if free shipping is active on my order page adding this code

```
<?php if ( array_key_exists('freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroups )) { $_shippingRateGroups = array('freeshipping' => $_shippingRateGroups['freeshipping']);}?>
```

on `app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/template checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

My problem though is that all shipping methods still appear on **"Estimate Shipping Block"**

So what i need is when free shipping is activated, other shipping options to be hidden on Estimate Shipping Block

Answer (score 5):

The file you need to adjust is:

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
```

Place the following code before the `<dl>` tag that displays the different options.

```
 <?php
if ( array_key_exists('freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroups )) {
unset($_shippingRateGroups["flatrate"]);
}
?>
```

I notified that above procedure not worked for you take a look at another procedure  [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-hide-shipping-method-on-magento-frontend-but-leave-it-on-in-admin-area/)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can go with other way to achieve what you need. 
Instead of creating one more shipping method in configuration which is called Free shipping you could set **Shopping cart price rule**. Then in Estimate shipping cost you will have automatic 0,00 in your shipping method staying same. It's not exact what you wanted in first place but in my opinion it's solving user experience problem with free shipping as he clearly can choose the shipping method of his choice with still seeing that he has achieved free shipping.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes

Answer (score 2):

Override the file at below location by copying it into your stores theme folder :

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

folder location to copy the above file :

```
app/design/frontend/yourtemplate/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
```

and add the code below exact before

```
<dl class="sp-methods">
```

tag,

code to be added :

```
<?php
    if ( array_key_exists('freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroups )) {
        $_shippingRateGroups = array('freeshipping' => $_shippingRateGroups['freeshipping']);
    }
?>
```